# como hacer que muestre le reporte si el campo esta vacio

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo

Estoy haciendo un popup en mi modulo de odoo que descarga informes avanzados dependiendo que opción se elija ya sea general(que este busca for fechas) o por empleado(que busca cualquier registro dependiendo el empleado que se busque) o por destino(que hace la misma función que empleado solo que por destino) pero esto y tratando de obtener el reporte general si yo elijo ya por empleado o por destino pero dejando esos campos vacíos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
asi como lo muestro en la imagen y si yo doy descarga pdf report me debe de mostrar esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ese es el reporte que me debe de mostrar cuando yo seleccione executive o country pero sus campos los deje vacíos pero cuando descargo cuakquiera de los dos reportes de executive o country dejando sus campos vacios me descarga los reportes asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
solo muestra los encabezados de la tabla pero sin la información

Adjunto código del modelo:

```
import json
import io
from xlsxwriter import workbook
from datetime import date
from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
try:
from odoo.tools.misc import xlsxwriter
except ImportError:
import xlsxwriter


class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"

from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de cotizacion")
to_date = fields.Date(string='Vencimiento')
type = fields.Selection(
    [('General', 'General'), ('Executive', 'Executive'), ('Country', 'Country')],
    string='Buscar por', default='General', reqired=True)
seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')

def _get_data(self):
    sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '!=', 'cancel')])
    validity_date = date.today()

    if self.from_date and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.from_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.from_date and not self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= validity_date,
                                  sale))
    else:
        sales_order = sale

    logger.info('**********sales_order*** {0}****'.format(sales_order))

    result = []
    seller = []
    country = []
    for rec in self.seller_id:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        seller.append(a)
        logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(seller))
    for rec in self.country_arrival:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        country.append(a)
        logger.info('**********country*** {0}****'.format(country))

    logger.info('*******Selecciono general %s ****' % self.type)
    if self.type == 'General':
        for so in sales_order:
            logger.info('**********result*** %s****' % so.date_order)

            if so.date_order:
                res = {
                    'name': so.name,
                    'date': so.date_order,
                    'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                    'validity': so.validity_date,
                    'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                    'seller': so.seller_id.name,
                    'country': so.country_arrival.name,
                    'freight': so.freight_type,
                    'gross': so.gross_weight,
                    'volume': so.volume,
                    'invoice': so.invoice_amount_assured,
                    'cotiza': so.name,
                }
                result.append(res)
                logger.info('**********result*** {0}****'.format(result))

    logger.info('*******Selecciono executive %s ****' % self.type)
    if self.type == 'Executive':
        for rec in seller:
            for so in sales_order:
                logger.info('***********result**** %s*****' % so.seller_id)

                if so.seller_id == rec['id']:
                    res = {
                        'name': so.name,
                        'date': so.date_order,
                        'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                        'validity': so.validity_date,
                        'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                        'country': so.country_arrival.name,
                        'freight': so.freight_type,
                        'gross': so.gross_weight,
                        'volume': so.volume,
                        'invoice': so.invoice_amount,
                    }
                    result.append(res)
                    logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(result))
    logger.info('*******EL campo de ejecutivo esta vacio y descargo el reporte general %s ****' % self.type)
    if self.type == 'Executive':
        for rec in seller:
            for so in sales_order:
                logger.info('**********result*** %s****' % so.date_order)
                if so.seller_id == rec[None]:
                    res = {
                        'name': so.name,
                        'date': so.date_order,
                        'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                        'validity': so.validity_date,
                        'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                        'seller': so.seller_id.name,
                        'country': so.country_arrival.name,
                        'freight': so.freight_type,
                        'gross': so.gross_weight,
                        'volume': so.volume,
                        'invoice': so.invoice_amount_assured,
                        'cotiza': so.name,
                    }
                    result.append(res)
                    logger.info('**********result*** {0}****'.format(result))
    if self.type == 'Country':
        for rec in country:
            for so in sales_order:
                logger.info('***********result**** %s*****' % so.date_order)

                if so.date_order == rec['id']:
                    res = {
                        'name': so.name,
                        'date': so.date_order,
                        'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                        'validity': so.validity_date,
                        'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                        'seller': so.seller_id.name,
                        'freight': so.freight_type,
                        'gross': so.gross_weight,
                        'volume': so.volume,
                        'invoice': so.invoice_amount,
                    }
                    result.append(res)
                    logger.info('**********country*** {0}****'.format(result))

    data = {
        'ids': self,
        'model': 'sale_report_general',
        'form': result,
        'seller_id': seller,
        'country_arrival': country,
        'type': self.type,
        'no_value': False,
        'employee': self.seller_id.name,
        'country': self.country_arrival.name,
        'from_date': self.from_date,
        'to_date': self.to_date
    }
    return data

def get_ventas_report(self):
    data = self._get_data()
    logger.info('**************Obtuvo el informe de ventas')
    return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_general_report').report_action(self, data=data)

    if self.date_order and self.validity_date and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        data['no_value'] = True
        return data
```

así es como tengo estructurado el mo0delo ahorita solo estoy probando con el reporte de empleados y de echo puse otro if parecido al que tengo de executive pero en el if donde puse que estajera la informacion es a donde no es ta entrando el proceso porque inclusive puse unos logger y solo esta entrando al logger donde dice que el campo esta vcio y que v aa descargar el general y de ahi se salta hasta el ulitmo logger que dice que se obtuvo el reporte que puedo hacer ahi para corregir eso y en el reporte que me esconda el encabezado de la tabla de ejecutivo

Comment: En primer lugar debes sustituir el nombre de tu variable `type` por otro de tu gusto, pero que no sea una palabra reservada o una `metaclase` de `python`, que es lo que es precisamente `type`: una metaclase que, entre otras cosas, permite definir tipos de forma dinámica. Por lo anterior, en tus bloques `if` estás intentando realizar una especie de comparación de tipos que nunca se va a dar y debe ser por eso que no entra en ninguno de los dos `if` y al menos un `log`...

Comment: a ok enotnves podria cambiar esa desicion por que identifique so el campo esta vacio? @FranciscoJavier

Comment: Esa es otra historia, primero cámbiale el nombre a la variable y comprueba que entra en los `if` y escribe en el `log`. Al menos eso quedará resuelto si es así...

Comment: ok deja lo intenti

Comment: la verdad ya me confundi porque mis if funcionan si el type e siual a alguna de las opciones que puse en el field.selection y de echo si esta entrando al loger que puse de quee l campo esta vacio etc etc y muestra cuantos registros se tienen pero no esta entrando a la informacion que traen dichos registros @FranciscoJavier

Comment: ya t eentendi jajaja

Comment: mira asi fue como lo puse @FranciscoJavier

logger.info('*******EL campo de ejecutivo esta vacio y descargo el reporte general %s ****' % self.type)
        if self.type == 'Executive':
                for so in sales_order:
                    logger.info('*****************result*********%s' % so.seller_id)

y entra solo hasta ese logger de ahi va  amas no entra al siguiente if

Comment: Es la segunda vez que lanzas la misma pregunta al foro sin obtener respuesta. Te recomiendo dedicar algo más de 5 minutos al proceso de consulta, ya sea pensando en cómo formular la pregunta; pero especialmente en esforzarte en escribirla correctamente y de forma que los demás podamos entenderla. De igual manera, en tus respuestas a comentarios parece que estés escribiendo en un chat de whatsapp, sin ninguna atención.